# Check if navigational property is loaded

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Is it possible to check if a navigational property has been loaded? When I try to access it I only get an `ObjectDisposedException`

> The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.

```
public class Factory {
    // ..
    public virtual ICollection<Machine> Machines { get; set; }
}

// ...
IList<Factory> set;
using (MyContext context = new MyContext()) {
    set = context.Factories.ToList();
}

... later on

// Is it possible to check if .Machines is loaded here?
if (set.First().Machines == Loaded)

    // Let's open a new context and load it then
}
```

The solution I have found when searching for this is to use `Include()` and just include the machines in the first run, but I would like to avoid loading it until neccessary. I also tried to box it in a new `using(...){}` but I still get the exception.
I'd also like to avoid `Attach` since it is extremely slow when building large object graphs.

I guess I could use a `bool IsMachinesLoaded` or something, but I figured there ought to be some way to check it without that..

Comment: Could the downvoter explain please? I have done my research and did not find a valid solution. I have tried different approaches that were not to my satisfaction. I have come to a minor dead end and I'm asking for assistance. Did I miss something?

Comment: Not my DV, but how is that condition meaningful? Either accessing `Machines` throws because you have disposed of the context, or else it's a collection -- possibly empty, but it can never be `null` because it's autoloaded on demand.

Comment: @Jon hm.. never actually thought of that. When I have hovered the `Machines` property in Visual Studio I think I've seen `null` sometime and figured that was a "valid" value. Although I see know that you are correct, hovering that property shows the exception. I'll edit the question to highlight that this is my issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved it with a method:

```
protected bool IsLoaded<TEntity>(TEntity entity, Func<TEntity, object> testAction)
{
    try
    {
        testAction(entity);
        return true;
    }
    catch (ObjectDisposedException)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

which is called via:

```
if (IsLoaded(myEntity, entity => entity.MyList)){
    // the navigational property exists and can be accesses
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to read .Machines inside your original DataContext scope, or specify Machines in .Include.

The reason for this is that you are disposing your DbContext before the Machines have been fetched. And when you are trying to fetch, it has no context to do so with. Therefore the ObjectDisposedException.

You cannot just wrap it in another using, as the original DbContext is still disposed, and that is what the entity is bound to.

Comment: I see.. so the entities are in fact "bound" to their original `DbContext` then? I've not thought of that. As I specified I'm not interested in loading it originally since they will be used much later. Is there no other way to even verify if it's loaded?

Comment: You can wrap it in another context providing you `Attach` it to that context.

Comment: @Shoe thanks, but as I stated `Attach` can be extremely slow when building those large object graphs, so I can't really use it. I actually went that path initially, but it got unbearable when loading entities took more than 1 minute (when to me it should take no more than 2 seconds)

Comment: So now you know about the different options you have, none which you actually want. Choose the one that sucks the least.