# Entity Framework Check virtual Lists after disposing of ObjectContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework

My scenario is I have an object `FOO` which has a `virtual List<bar>` property on it. This is being auto generated by EF.

After I load `FOO` I dispose of the data context, I am turning `FOO` into a business object through a DTO. For example

```
var newFOO = FOO_Dto.change(FOO);
```

Inside of `FOO_Dto.change` I want to check if the virtual list property is empty/null. **I understand that closing the ObjectContext and checking the navigation property will throw an error**. In My Data Layer there are times when I return `FOO` with the list and `FOO` without the list.

My Question is how do I check the Navigation Property to see if the list has been populated or not and avoid the ObjectContext error that is currently generating

Thank you very much!!

**EDIT**

From the comments section, I purposely want the context closed before I check to see if I loaded the `List<Bar>` property.

Comment: Call the `change` method before disposing the context.

Comment: @hami770 the only method I see is the `changetracker` on the context

Comment: duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22545823/check-if-navigational-property-is-loaded

Comment: @haim770 could you expand on that, maybe provide some links? I have never seen the "change" method in [DbContexts methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext_methods%28v=vs.113%29.aspx)

Comment: I wrote `change` after your `FOO_Dto.change(FOO)`. There is not `change` method in `DbContext`.

Comment: oh, that `change`.. it's been a long day.

Comment: @hami770 I do not want to call it before the context is closed. The question is how can i view virtual properties after I close the context.

Comment: You can try to `Include` it beforehand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't, other than the ugly way of trying and catching the exception. You can only determine whether a collection is loaded by getting the owner's `DbEntityEntry`, which you can only obtain through a context instance.

But if you know up front that the collection may be addressed outside the scope of the context, you need to load it while the context is alive, OR not load it and prevent lazy loading. You should never allow lazy loading to occur outside the lifespan of a context.

In most cases this means you'll have to turn off lazy loading and eagerly load all data required by a consuming method.

The more I work with EF in a disconnected fashion the less I allow lazy loading. I'm close to considering lazy loading an anti-pattern.